# How to append mysql access to iptables

Tags: mysql, iptables, port

On one of my servers, I can see this:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  distinct_server_ip               anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
```

By doing

```
sudo iptables -L | grep distinct_server_ip
```

And with

```
iptables -L -n -v | grep 3306

432K   26M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       mydistinctip       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
90  5400 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       mydistinctip2       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
```

I would like to enable the same in another server, could you please help me with the command I have to use?

I was thinking on something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s distinct_server_ip --sport 1024:65535 -d this_server_ip --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: We can't help, because you haven't told us enough about the first rule.  Please give the relevant piece of output of `iptables -L -n -v`, not just `iptables -L`.

Comment: Thank you, question edited with `iptables -L -n -v | grep 3306`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables` is highly dependent on the order of your rules. Your question isn't entirely clear so I'll go over both possibilities of you may be aiming to do.

On `ServerA`, if you want to allow `ServerB` to connect to it:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s ServerB --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

And, for egress rules on `ServerB` (not recommended), if you want to allow it to connect to `ServerA`:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d ServerA --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Huge caveat: You may have something in the `INPUT` or `OUTPUT` chain that may prevent these rules from ever being processed. To advise on that, we would need to see all your rules.

Comment: NP, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that simply, because `iptables` accepts only a single ip its rules (the same don't stand for ports, they can be multiple generated by the `mport` module, which is loaded by `iptables` on the need automatically).

There is a possibility, that you simply duplicate your rules. It is not always practical, although very simple.

Or you could emulate the multi-ip behavior were to create a new table to filter your given list of ip-s. For example:

```
Chain MY_WISHLIST (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       1.2.3.4/19       0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       1.2.0.0/17        0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       1.3.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       1.4.128.0/20      0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       1.5.152.0/21      0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       1.6.0.0/15        0.0.0.0/0
```

...and you can refer this chain from anywhere:

```
0 0 MY_WISHLIST        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19
```

---

Finally, there is a new development around the linux kernel/networking things, and that is `ipset`. Ipset handles exactly this actual flaw (?) of iptables, it will be the 4th firewalling command line tool for linux (after ipfwadm, ipchains and our current iptables).